# How to monitor read write activities on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, monitoring, azure-monitoring

Need to figure out how to log/retrieve information about who (which Azure AD user) has read/write on blobs in our azure blob storage.

I know you can turn on logging on the storage account level using this:

[image]

I can see in the logs the different api calls that have been performed on the blob but If I myself went via the azure portal to open some of the blobs, I could not see this activity recorded in the logs. Any ideas how to monitor this? I need it for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you [enable Storage Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account) on Portal, you will have `$logs` folder on your Blob with storage logs.

When you are using Azure AD authentication you need to configure [2.0 logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format#log-entry-format-20) and use `UserPrincipalName` column to identify the user and parse the column with JSON `AuthorizationDetail.action` to identify the action of the user on storage, i.e. `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read` for list the blobs in a container.

You will not capture OAuth/Azure AD authenticated requests with log format 1.0.

On Azure Storage Uservoice there is also the request for [integration with LogAnalytics](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33930541-make-it-possible-to-send-storage-analytics-logs) to simplify logs monitoring, the private preview should start this month.

Comment: Awesome and informative answer! thanks a lot! Also I realized pretty quickly that an integration towards the log analytics would be a huge help!